# Azure AD users are not moving to license group automatically

Tags: excel, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have created Dynamic Group for assigning License to All Azure AD user automatically using powershell in production Environment.

Here is my script:

`New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "us_demo_group" -Description " your Descriptions-MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -membershipRule "(user.department -contains ""Marketing"")" -membershipRuleProcessingState "On"

Add-AADGroupLicenseAssignment -groupId "a5e95316-1c03-44d7-afac-efd0e788122c" -accountSkuId "your skuid:FLOW_FREE"
`

My script is working fine, but when I tried to create a bulk users using Excel File, Users are not getting License, always showing **No License assignment Found **.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to assign the license to Azure AD user dynamically using power shell**

I have created Azure dynamic group using powerShell, name-**TestGroup1** with condition.

```
#Install  AzureADLicensing Module
Install-Module -Name AzureADLicensing
#Import AzureADPreview
Import-Module AzureADPreview
#Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "TestGroup1" -Description "This group contains information of users from us domain" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -membershipRule "(user.department -contains ""Finance"")" -membershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

[image]

TestGroup1 created once execute the above code.

[image]

**Assign the license to group, like below**

```
#Get All License with SKUID
Get-AADGroupLicenseAssignment -All
```

You can fetch the group ID, like below.

[image]

```
#Assign License to Group
Add-AADGroupLicenseAssignment -groupId "GroupIDObject ID" -accountSkuId "Your SKUID"
```

[image]

[image]

Create bulk user in Azure Active Directory, like below.

**Azure Portal > Default Directory > Users > Bulk Operations > Bulk Create**

> Make sure mention the department value for moving the users to dynamic group automatically.

Download the excel file and add the value in excel and save, like below.

[image]

Once add the value in excel and **Upload** the excel to Azure, like below.

[image]

**Successfully created bulk- users with license in Azure AD.**

[image]

You can view the users in assigned group.

[image]

License assigned to group users automatically.

[image]

Successfully assigned Azure license to created users.

[image]